# Lenovo Thinkpad E480 No screen or Post - Fresh Install 18.04

Tags: boot, lenovo, 18.04, thinkpad, secure-boot

So today I got my brand new Lenovo Thinkpad E480 (no OS) and rush to install Ubuntu 18.04 on it.

After I was done with the install, Ubuntu started to boot up and told me to remove the media drive to continue => remove and nothing happened => pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> => laptop rebooted but there was no screen nor post sound.

Since then I can't boot the laptop or to get into BIOS, there is no response.

- I forgot to turn off secureboot and fastboot in BIOS before installing Ubuntu (too excited).
- Tried to unplug the battery to fix the issue.
- Tried to disconnect all media to make the laptop to perform full
  POST, the only thing that made a sound is removing the RAM.

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 0):

The most aggressive solution is to open the laptop and remove the bios battery for 10-15 seconds 
This will reset the bios state

Comment: Won't help, both CMOS and laptop battery were disconnected, no change.